# undefined variable confusion codeigniter active records

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

I have the following code,

This is where i process the textfield input type wherein i type in the ingredient of an recipe.
The proper format of how one should input the ingredient is like this.

5-ml milk, 4-ml water, 2-pcs carrot

There are always delimiter in between since i have different columns for quantity, unit of measurement and the name.

I have no problem with the separation. I have another table. Which is named ingredients.
This is where i populate different ingredients like milk and put in what food group they belong and their nutritional info(what it gives off, like calcium).

Anyhow, I get a database error, Somehow, when i try to insert after all that processing, both the type and nutrition are null. I've thought about it, maybe my query was wrong? but it didnt give off any warning or notice. Though it only gave me notice/warning that both the values are undefined when i tried to declare them at array $comp which are the values to be inserted.

I get this error,

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'nutrition' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `component` (`componentname`, `quantity`, `unit`,
>   `nutrition`, `type`) VALUES ('milk', '5', 'ml', NULL, NULL)
>
> Filename: C:\www\KG\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

The code:

```
function insertrecipe()
    {
        $ingredients = $this->input->post('ingredients');
        $recipename = $this->input->post('recipename');

        $recipe = array(
            'recipename' => $recipename,
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'instruction' => $this->input->post('instructions'),
            'serving' => $this->input->post('serving'),
            );      

        $this->db->insert('recipe', $recipe);

        $this->ingredient($ingredients,$recipename);
    }

    function ingredient($ingredients,$recipename)
    {
    $ids = array();
    $first_slice = explode(',',$ingredients);
    $secondslice = $this->second_slice($first_slice);


            foreach($secondslice as $qty => $iname)
            {
                $arr = explode('-',$qty);
                $third_slice[$arr[1]] = $arr[0];

                $sql = $this->db
                            ->select('nutrition,group')
                            ->where('ingname', $iname)
                            ->from('ingredients')
                            ->get()
                            ->result_array();

                $result = $this->db->query($sql);

                foreach($result->result_array() as $row)
                {
                $ingredient_type = $this->get_ingredient_type($row['group']);
                }

                foreach($third_slice as $measure => $num)
                {
                $comp = array(
                                'componentname' => $iname,
                                'quantity' => $num,
                                'unit' => $measure,
                                'nutrition' => $nutri,
                                'type' => $ingredient_type
                                );
                    if($insert2 = $this->db->insert('component',$comp))
                    {   
                        $latest_id = $this->db->insert_id();

                        $ids[] = $latest_id;
                    }
                }

            }
    }



    function second_slice($data)
    {
            foreach($data as $key => $value)
            {
            $ingredient = explode(' ', trim($value));
            $second_slice[$ingredient[0]] = $ingredient[1];
            }

    return $second_slice;
    }


    function get_ingredient_type($data)
    {
                //foreach($data->result_array() as $row)
                //{ 
                    if($data['group'] == "vegetable")
                    {
                        $type = 1;
                    }
                    else if($data['group'] == "fruit")
                    {
                        $type = 2;
                    }
                    else if($data['group'] == "dairy")
                    {
                        $type = 3;
                    }
                    else if($data['group'] == "seafood")
                    {
                        $type = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $type = 5;
                    }
                //}
    return $type;
    }
```

The database  table of component has the following columns.

```
componentid componentname   quantity    unit    nutrition   type
```

nutrition is varchar unit is int. I guess they're not null or cols that dont accept null values.

I've separated different foreach loops into functions. I originally thought the error was because i had 3-5 for each loop within that function alone. so i decided to separate them into functions.

Comment: Ive been editing my code. I also would appreciate coding suggestions. Like if theres a better way to do something ive done.

Comment: print the database tables also

Comment: The problem is when i insert both values are null. Its not really the table. i think, Somehow, im quite confused atm.

Anyways i edited.